# Python getting the unique and smallest value pairs from two lists with same length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have two lists:

```
index = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10]
value = [2,3,2,1,2,4,6,8,2,1,5,2,7,2,2,2,1,55,1,11]
```

Same length but what I want in return are unique number from index list and smallest value of the value list according to the index

Result should be like:

```
index_result = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

value_result = [1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1]
```

I have tried:

```
index = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10]
value = [2,3,2,1,2,4,6,8,2,1,5,2,7,2,2,2,1,55,1,11]
index_result = []
value_result = []
#global small_value
j = 0
while j < len(index):
    if j == 0:
        try:
            if index[j] == index[j+1]:
                small_value = min(value[j],value[j+1])
            elif index[j] != index[j+1]:
                index_result.append(index[j])
                value_result.append(value[j])
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        j = j + 1
        print('small value is for index j ==0')
        print(small_value)
    elif j <len(index) - 1:
        try:
            # if index[j] == index[j-1]:
            #     small_value = min(value[j],value[j-1])
            if index[j] != index[j+1] and index[j] != index[j-1]:
                index_result.append(index[j])
                value_result.append(value[j])
            elif index[j] != index[j+1] and index[j] == index[j-1]:
                index_result.append(index[j])
                value_result.append(small_value)
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        j = j + 1
        print('small value is for index 0 < j <len(index)')
        print(small_value)
    elif j == len(index) - 1:
        try:
            if index[j] == index[j-1]:
                small_value = min(value[j],value[j-1])
                index_result.append((index[j]))
                value_result.append(small_value)
            elif index[j] != index[j-1]:
                index_result.append(index[j])
                value_result.append(value[j])
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        j = j + 1
        print('small value is for j = len(index) - 1')
        print(small_value)

print (index_result)
print (value_result)
```

The result is close to what expect but still wrong:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]

Comment: `...and smallest value of the value list according to the index` what does that mean?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'value': value, 'index':index}).groupby('index').min()`?

Comment: Yup had same answer, @QuangHoang

Comment: @JerryM. sorry for my English but it means:
1. index list should only have unique no redundant number
2. the value list should return the smallest value from the value pool that pairs with the index list

for example: for two lits: index [1,1,2]  and [3,4,6], result should be index [1,2] and [3,6]

Comment: @QuangHoang Can I hug you!? Thanks a lot

Comment: @QuangHoang quick follow up question, do you know how can I plot the index as x and value as y?

df.plot(x=index, y= value, style='o') gave me error 'KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"'

and df.plot(x='index', y= 'value', style='o')
 also gave me error: KeyError: 'index'

Comment: Pass `'index'`, the string, not the array. Same for value?

Answer (score 3):

Since you tag pandas

```
pd.DataFrame([index,value]).T.sort_values([0,1]).drop_duplicates(0)
     0  1
3    1  1
4    2  2
8    3  2
9    4  1
11   5  2
13   6  2
14   7  2
15   8  2
16   9  1
18  10  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted to achieve

```
import math

indices = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10]
values = [2,3,2,1,2,4,6,8,2,1,5,2,7,2,2,2,1,55,1,11]

result = [math.inf] * max(indices)

for i, v in zip(indices, values):
    result[i-1] = min(result[i-1], v) # Apparently 1 based indexing

print(result)

[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `index` is *monotonic-increasing* as in the sample, you may try this python solution using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {k: min([x[1] for x in g]) for k, g in groupby(zip(index, value), 
                                                     lambda x: x[0])}

In [95]: d
Out[95]: {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 1}

index_result = list(d.keys())

Out[103]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

value_result = list(d.values())

Out[105]: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy solution:

```
index = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10])
value = np.array([2,3,2,1,2,4,6,8,2,1,5,2,7,2,2,2,1,55,1,11])

[value[index == i].min() for i in np.unique(index)]
# [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] index list? Like a unique.function?

Comment: @DaweiZhang `list(dict.from_iterable(index))`